# Salesforce download Document Body with Ruby and restforce gem

Tags: rest-api, ruby

i try to download a file from Salesforce using restforce with Ruby.

https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce

```
sf_template = client.find("Document", "015b0000002oWdu")
```

i get my document, but when i try to access the content.

```
sf_template.Body
=> **/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Document/015b0000002oWduAAE**
```

from restforce wiki: https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce#downloading-attachments

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? It's a little hard to tell the exact nature of your question.

Comment: haven't used the Ruby restforce gem, but have you tried the example provided in the documentation that you linked to (ie, using `query` instead of `find`)?

Answer (score 0):

With the REST API, on which the gem is based, it isn't common to bring back Blob data in a retrieve for an sObject. Instead you will get another resource path that will just bring back the data. See [Get Attachment Content from a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm).

I'm don't know Ruby as a language. Scanning the [source](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce/blob/04ade41037ff952b70e1d6c2855906d3dd43eab1/lib/restforce/concerns/api.rb#L396) for that project makes it look like you need to do a `api_get` call to the resource you want.

Comment: I agree with what you said. The problem was the Restforce docs were misleading. I filed an issue against their docs which has subsequently been resolved: https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce/issues/301

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this myself. It appears the docs are erroneous regarding how to download the body of a Document to a local file. As you pointed out, you get back a URL for the body. To actually get the body, and save it to a file you must do the following:

```
document = client.query("SELECT Id, Name, Body FROM Document WHERE FolderId = '#{folder.Id}').first
# Get the resource at the URL returned as "Body". This returns a Faraday::Response object
resp = client.get(document.Body)
File.open(document.Name, 'wb') { |f| f.write(resp.body) }
```